# Dependabot does not find latest commit

Tags: github, dependabot

I'm exploring how Dependabot works and it isn't working as I expect.

I've created 2 **private** Golang repos (`one`, `two`) with `one` depending on `two`:

`one`'s `go.mod`:

```
module github.com/dazwilkin/one

go 1.17

require github.com/dazwilkin/two v0.0.0-20210927170438-e7aa41e4107b
```

> **NOTE** `e7aa41e4107b` is a prior commit intentionally in order to check VS Code's and Dependabot's update checking.

And `dependabot.yml`:

```
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "gomod"
    directory: "/"
    schedule:
      interval: "daily"
```

`two`'s 2 most recent commits are:

```sh
curl \
--silent \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
https://api.github.com/repos/${OWNER}/${REPO}/commits \
| jq -r '.[]|{"sha":.sha,"date":.commit.committer.date}'
```

And:

```
{
  "sha": "b2f2074829aa61218d7e38f27bb6051ccd97ab7a",
  "date": "2021-09-27T18:03:33Z"
}
{
  "sha": "e7aa41e4107b8c28f99cadfe55b831380730e808",
  "date": "2021-09-27T17:04:38Z"
}
```

> **NOTE** `b2f2074829aa` is the commit I'm expecting to be told about and `e7aa41e4107b` is the prior commit on `two` that `one` continues to reference.

VS Code quickly determined that an update is available and:

```sh
go list -m -u all

github.com/dazwilkin/one
github.com/dazwilkin/two v0.0.0-20210927170438-e7aa41e4107b [v0.0.0-20210927180333-b2f2074829aa]
```

> **NOTE** Correctly identifying the latest commit (`b2f2074829aa`) to replace the prior commit (`e7aa41e4107b`)

But, after 22 hours and repeated forced updates, `dependabot` continues to report that `e7aa41e4107b` is current:

```
updater | INFO <job_214390230> Starting job processing
updater | INFO <job_214390230> Starting update job for DazWilkin/one
updater | INFO <job_214390230> Checking if github.com/dazwilkin/two 0.0.0-20210927170438-e7aa41e4107b needs updating
updater | INFO <job_214390230> Latest version is 0.0.0-20210927170438-e7aa41e4107b
updater | INFO <job_214390230> No update needed for github.com/dazwilkin/two 0.0.0-20210927170438-e7aa41e4107b
updater | INFO <job_214390230> Finished job processing
```

> **NOTE** Dependabot appears to have no issue accessing `github.com/dazwilkin/two` but it doesn't find the most recent commit.

Is this just an eventual consistency issue and I need wait longer?

> **Update** I've waited another 24 hours and it continues to find the earlier commit as the `latest version`

Or am I misunderstanding or misconfiguring Dependabot?

One perhaps relevant issue that my GitHub account is mixed-case `DazWilkin` but, for simplicity, I'm publishing and referencing the Golang Modules using all-lowercase (`github.com/dazwilkin`). However Dependabot appears to have no issues finding the prior commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is because dependabot doesn't support pseudoversions - https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/3017

Comment: Aha! Yes, I think that's it, thanks!